# How can you Interact and log in to the physical steam client using Python?

Tags: python, steam

In summary; I want to be able to interact with a non-logged in steam client and log it in, and I dont want to use some type of Windows only interaction. I don't mean the SteamCLI, or logging into steam using the steam library for python. I mean directly interacting with the steam client in some way and physically logging in.

When using SteamCLI and other modules I've noticed it just logs you into *their* session instead of the client session that you get from physically logging into steam.

for example:

```
from steam.client import SteamClient
x = SteamClient()
x.login(username=, password=)
```

Doesn't actually log you in, since it is its own client.

I need this because I have made a script that can connect me to servers and figure out who's on it, and it relies on you being logged in to said client.

Is there any modules/libraries that will allow me to do this? and if pywinauto is the one I should use, are there any guides you know of so I can interact with said application in a *good* way, even on linux.

Comment: Don't call it a "physical client", it's more of a "GUI client"

Comment: I've never used it, but I Googled for built-in [command line arguments](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options) of official Steam program (`steam.exe` stored somewhere where your Steam is installed). There you can see you can pass a `login` argument with username and password. I would expect it would open the GUI Steam client without log in window, but straight logged in

Comment: @AlexLarionov Thanks for the help, I might have to dig around for steam.exe/steam executable flags... I heard they weren't documented very well anywhere. Ill give it a look

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I ended up doing:

First you get a dummy display. I used this https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in

After that you create the config (https://askubuntu.com/a/463000) and start up the display.

Next I created a systemd unit to launch steam using command line

```
[Unit]
Description=example systemd service unit file.

[Service]
User=root
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(you probably shouldn't be using root for this, but its the easiest way I found to always have perms to the XAUTHORITY env, so you can login to the display)

Here is what `/root/start.sh` looks like

```
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/games"
steam -login username_goes_here password_goes_here steam_guard_code
```

Note that you may not need to do the `export DISPLAY` and `export XAUTHORITY` twice. I haven't tested it.

This should just work™, it will log in, but it will ask for a steam guard code, so what you should do is attempt to start the service, receive the code through email, then append it after password.

As for doing this in python, as I said originally. you can probably use it to call start.sh, implementing command line arguments for steam code. You need these arguments because I haven't found a way for it to trust the computer you use, so it might be beneficial to implement python IMAP for reading the codes sent to the email which owns the account and using said arguments.

### Theoretical Section

Please note this whole section is untested, but intended to answer my original question.

Heres what a python file might look like (very roughly)

```
def start_steam(code=""):
    # Assuming start.sh includes reading variables from cmd line (my example didnt)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "start.sh", code])

    # This function would probably just interact iwth an IMAP server to retrieve an email sent by steam support with the code. If its not found within a certain range of time, it would theoretically just stop looking
    steam_guard_code = do_something_to_find_steam_guard_code_email(timeout=30)
    
    if code:
        proc.terminate()
        start_steam(code=code)
    else:
        # proc should continue to run in the background, until restart, that means this script should ALSO run on startup, or until there isnt a PID detected for steam
        with open("/var/run/steam.pid", "w") as f:
            f.write(process.pid)
        exit()
```

this python script would have to be run by `systemd`, it would be a forking process, and `PIDfile` would have to be specified by `systemd` (I think) so that it can be monitored.

edit: this solution has become even more theoretical, since it is not possible to pass steam guard code to `steam -login username password`. You would need to disable steam guard.